# Pass wordpress form data to checkout Page of shopify?

Tags: wordpress, forms, checkout, shopify

I create shopify shop and integrate it in wordpress website.And now I want to pass the custom form(created in wordpress) data to shopify checkout page.Data such as email,telephone,name etc.IS it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify API doesn't allow to create orders from outside services. You indeed can create carts with products / variants in cart (outside Shopify) and force the user to finish the buying process at PCI compliant Shopify checkout, which has 2 steps: (considering s/he is not authed)

A.- Buyer enters billing / shipping info as well as email address.

B.- Buyer enters discount coupon/s, chooses shipping method, enters payment info (credit card, paypal, wire, cod...)

Checkout url will look like: checkout.shopify.com/carts/your_store_id/cart_id